# PHP Local File Inclusion from URL; no param

Tags: php, nginx, lfi

The PHP code has a `handleRoute($path)` function that is triggered for URLs like `server.com/routeme/a`. Handle route has the follwing: if `file_exists($path)` then `include $path`.

The $path argument is `/srv/dirs/routeme/a`.

A Google search leads to a million results where the file name is directly read from a parameter. When instead read from an URL, I can't just say `server.com/routeme/a/../../`, as nginx will reply with `400 Bad Request` instead of executing the `handleRoute` function.

I have been attempting to find something that PHP will interpret as a Path outside of `routeme/` while nginx does not and thus still lead to the execution of the include.

I was hoping `%2E%2E%2F` (encoded `../`) would do it, but nginx still interprets this as a path.

I have a feeling that either I'm missing some obvious method to do this, or that it is a dead end and the code not vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible unless the HTTP Daemon itself is either in the root directory (e.g. in **/** rather than **/var/www/html**) OR if the HTTP Daemon itself is a superuser.

Unless I'm misreading your text and not properly grasping what you're trying to say here, I don't think this is a possibility without the httpd being in root dir.. I've came across instances where LFI/LFD has been possible simply by appending the path to the end of a URL, but like I said, only in instances wherein the HTTP Daemon itself is installed in the root directory, rather than the webroot.. If it's installed properly (e.g. in the webroot) then I think it will always be considered a URL Path as opposed to a path to a local system file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you want to do is use a diffrent root for a subset of your vhost.

if so, this can be done by using a `location` block with a `root` element inside  the nginx vhost.
you can lookup the nginx recommended instructions for drupal or wordpress for more information on how to make that work with loading  sript a (index.php in there case) while serving url "b" (like {domain}/api/path/target). aka the clean urls philosophy.